# Unsure how to add simple checkboxes that write to a small table to admin

Tags: admin, post-meta, actions, admin-menu

I've been doing a lot of reading on the add_meta_boxes...but there's so much information that I'm confused about when to use them.  I have a little plugin that writes out some checkboxes and then when a post is saved with those checkboxes checked, a row is saved in a separate table I created to enforce post_id to image relationship.  My checkboxes show up fine in wp_admin, but I have a front facing way to edit some custom post types for qualified users and the checkboxes don't show up in that case.  I was trying to hook them into dbx_post_sidebar, but further research shows that may be deprecated.

I just don't know if add_meta_boxes would add my checkboxes to my front facing edit screens (the front facing part is Event Manager and it let's users submit events without going into wp-admin), in this case, and how to really implement them in the easiest way possible.  Frankly, they seem quite complicated.  I can't get my head around whether or not I need to use callbacks or how to hook into a page (by name?  do I need to specify a page?).

My plugin code is here: http://pastebin.com/Ztp01k0q

Here's where I do my add_action stuff:

```
# actions we use to get stuff done
add_action('activate_ixp-amenities-icons/ixpposticon.php', array(&$this, 'install'));           // install
add_action('deactivate_ixp-amenities-icons/ixpposticon.php', array(&$this, 'uninstall'));       // uninstall
add_action('wp_head', array(&$this, 'style'));                                                                          // load style
add_action('dbx_post_sidebar', array(&$this, 'checkboxes'));                                                    // checkboxes
//add_action('dbx_post_advanced', array(&$this, 'checkboxes'));
//add_action('admin_menu', array(&$this, 'checkboxes'));
//add_meta_box( 'hello', 'hello', 'None', 'location', 'normal', 'default', null);
add_action('publish_post', array(&$this, 'save'));                                                                      // publish
add_action('save_post', array(&$this, 'save'));                                                                         //save
add_action('edit_post', array(&$this, 'edit'));                                                                         // edit...this sin't firing yet
add_action('delete_post', array(&$this, 'delete'));                                                                     // delete
add_action('admin_menu', array(&$this, 'adminMenu'));                                                           // adminMenu
```

Comment: Quite frankly I don't understand most of what you say, but why don't you try http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/ ? It's really easy and powerful

Comment: Ok.  I'll give that a try.  All I was trying to do was to add checkboxes to wp-admin's edit post area.  Which worked. But I'm using the Event Manager plugin which allows users to also add posts on the front end and my checkboxes didn't appear there.  I don't know why.  But Wordpress is sort of a complicated beast and I'm just trying to find out if there is an action or hook I can use to make my checkboxes show up on the front facing edit post area.